# HWIOAuthBundle get birthday, gender after Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, symfony, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle

as per documentation I am able to configure and store Facebook ID to FOSUserBundle Entity User

I want to store birthday and gender also.

## app/config/config.yml

```
hwi_oauth:
    firewall_name:         secured_area
    resource_owners:
        facebook:
            type:          facebook
            client_id:     <client_id>
            client_secret: <client_secret>
            scope:         "email,user_birthday"
```

in documentation there is some description [Here](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/internals/response_object_and_paths.md) but I am unable to get it work. as I am beginner here this documentation isn't helpful to me.

where can I get facebook response which contains all local data.

I need to store that data also along with other FOSUserBundle Fields.

Comment: at least tell me how can I improve this question as it got downvoted

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your config would look like this:

```
facebook:
    type:          facebook
    client_id:     %client_id%
    client_secret: %client_secret%
    scope:         "email, basic_info, user_birthday"
    infos_url:     "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,email,first_name,last_name,gender,birthday"
```

Then on your `AccountConnector` service / or how you handle the response you can do something like this:

```
$data = $response->getResponse();
//check if all fields are set 
...
$user->setLastname($data['last_name']);
$user->setBirthdate(new \DateTime($data['birthday']));
$user->setGender($this->setGender($data['gender']));
$user->setEmail($data['email']);
```

Since Facebook sends nominal values for gender, I have created the `setGender` function.

```
private function setGender($gender) {
    return ($gender === 'male') ? '1' : '0' ;
}
```

Comment: I used `FOSUserBundle` as `hwi_oauth.user.provider.fosub_bridge` so I should add this in User.php entity class ? or somewhere else ?

Comment: also i am redirecting user to /user/like route after successful login

Comment: You should create your own service and extend `hwi_oauth.user.provider.fosub_bridge` default class. A good example can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697).